# Can this spec do smooth and lag free flash?

Tags: flash, hardware

I'm about to buy the following spec:

```
CPU: Intel Core i3 2100 3.10 GHz
RAM: 16Gb 1600MHz
GPU: 2x GT 430 1Gb
```

Ignoring the RAM which I need for VM's and the 2x GPU's which I need for 4 monitors.  My question is, will that CPU and those GPU's be able to playback youtube flash videos at 1080p smoothly and will they be able to run the following web flash based applications without lag?

```
http://www.sumopaint.com/app/
http://www.homestyler.com/designer
```

I currently have:

```
CPU: Pentium D 3.0GHz
GPU: Builtin to motherboard
RAM: 3Gb
```

and it can't do 1080p flash smoothly and those flash based applications have a lot of lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so. I've got a Pentium D too, but with an AMD gpu, and it runs HD smoothly. With your configuration it will run even smoother ;)